# how to execute html code in php, my code doesn't work

Tags: php, html, echo

cant seem to run this code with php and html. I tried running it as html file and a php file and still doesn't run. It needs to look like a restaurant receipt. what am I missing?

```
<?php
$item1="Penne Alla Vodka w/ Chicken";
$q1=1;
$p1=15.95;
$item2="Baby Back Ribs Deluxe";
$q2=1;
$p2=20;
$item3="Vodka Martini";
$q3=1;
$p3=9;
$item4="Tiramisu";
$q4=1;
$p4=8.50;
$subtotal=($p1*$q1)+($p2*$q2)+($p3*$q3)+($p4*$q4);
$tax=0.08875*$subtotal;
$tip=0.2*$subtotal;
$finaltotal=$subtotal+$tax+$tip;
$host="Alia";
```

here breaks the php code
and the html code begins

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

th, td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left:
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>
Invoice
</h2>
```

it mostly outputs the actually code itself and not the current time

```
<p> Bar & Grill</p>
echo date("Y/m/d")."<br>";
echo date("h:i:sa");
echo $host;

    <table style="width:50%">
        <caption> Bill</caption>
        <tr>
            echo "<th>Qty</th>";
            echo "<th>Desc</th>";
            echo "<th>Amt</th>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>$q1</td>";
            echo "<td>$item1</td>";
            echo "<td>$p1</td>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>$q2</td>";
            echo "<td>$item2</td>";
            echo "<td>$p2</td>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>$q3</td>";
            echo "<td>$item3</td>";
            echo "<td>$p3</td>";
        </tr>
            <tr>
            echo "<td>$q4</td>";
            echo "<td>$item4</td>";
            echo "<td>$p4</td>";
        </tr>
    echo</table>
    echo "AMT" .<br>.$subtotal;
    echo "Subtotal".<br>.$subtotal;
    echo "Tax".<br>.$tax;
    echo "Balance".<br>.$finaltotal;

    </body>
    </html>
    ?>
```

Comment: Place PHP code inside `<?php ?>`. Anything outside can/will be HTML. `...$host="Alia";?>` ... HTML follows ... `<?php echo date("Y/m/d")."<br>";`

Comment: You can read more about the php tags (the `<?php ?>` that @kerbholz mentions) in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here first of all you PHP code must be placed in the `<?php ?>` tags. And second of all your syntax for echoing the variables in the table is wrong(*in string format*) and that's the reason you are not getting their values

*Change your code to*

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$item1="Penne Alla Vodka w/ Chicken";
$q1=1;
$p1=15.95;
$item2="Baby Back Ribs Deluxe";
$q2=1;
$p2=20;
$item3="Vodka Martini";
$q3=1;
$p3=9;
$item4="Tiramisu";
$q4=1;
$p4=8.50;
$subtotal=($p1*$q1)+($p2*$q2)+($p3*$q3)+($p4*$q4);
$tax=0.08875*$subtotal;
$tip=0.2*$subtotal;
$finaltotal=$subtotal+$tax+$tip;
$host="Alia";
?>
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

th, td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left:
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>
Invoice
</h2>
<p> Bar & Grill</p>
echo date("Y/m/d")."<br>";
echo date("h:i:sa");
echo $host;

    <table style="width:50%">
        <caption> Bill</caption>
        <tr>
            echo "<th>".Qty."</th>";
            echo "<th>".Desc."</th>";
            echo "<th>".Amt."</th>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>".$q1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$item1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p1."</td>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>".$q2."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$item2."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p2."</td>";
        </tr>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>".$q3."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$item3."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p3."</td>";
        </tr>
            <tr>
            echo "<td>".$q4."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$item4."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p4."</td>";
        </tr>
    echo</table>
    echo "AMT <br>".$subtotal;
    echo "Subtotal <br>".$subtotal;
    echo "Tax <br>".$tax;
    echo "Balance <br>".$finaltotal;
    </body>
    </html>
```